# can't find the deactivate() function on MemoryFile class

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm importing this project from another file, and everything else goes well except for this strange piece of code snippet

```
           MemoryFile memoryFile = new MemoryFile(null, length);
           memoryFile.writeBytes(buffer, 0, 0, length);
           memoryFile.deactivate();
           return AssetFileDescriptor.fromMemoryFile(memoryFile);
```

eclipse complains that deactivate function does not exist in the MemoryFile class,
as well as AssetFileDescriptor not having the fromMemoryFile function.
This is strange because according to the following links, [deactivate](http://hi-android.info/doc/android/os/MemoryFile.html#deactivate%28%29) and [fromMemoryFile](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html#fromMemoryFile%28android.os.MemoryFile%29) functions exist.
But the SDK can't seem to find them, or the android.jar doesn't seem to contain them.

The real strange thing is that the two functions "don't exist" in the 'Official Android Documentation'.

I changed the "Project Build Target" on Properties->Android from Android 2.1 to 2.3 but the problem persists.
I also did a wide search on the net, but oddly enough, "nobody" has ever asked on the same problem.

Any advice? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably copying the code from some internal classes. The `deactivate()` and `fromMemoryFile()` are hidden apis (annotated with `@hide` in the source) and not meant for application developers to use.

Comment: is there any way to use those hidden APIs? Those are the only two errors, and if there is some way to expose those hidden APIs from android.jar so that the compiler can recognize them, then I think the errors will go away...

Comment: There are some ways you can get to that: 1) If the required files are independent utility classes, you can copy them into your project and use them 2) Another unrecommended way is there, if you have an aosp built on your system: use the `classes-debug-full.jar` from `framework_intermediates` in `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES` and include it as a system library in your project. This jar has all the internal apis, and hence the project will build. But this may break if you try to run it on any other build than the one from which you took the jar from.

Comment: I followed this post(http://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=ncs10066&logNo=80156493486) and got it fixed! :) The 'hidden APIs' was an awesome hint to solve the problem. Great thanks! XDDD